# MATLAB/SIMULINK dynamic bus conversion with embedded Matlab function

Tags: matlab, dynamic, simulink, bus

I'm working on automated model building. In some cases I have do convert a bus into another bus (the structure is the same, but there can be variants in the names). It works for a static model where I can change the datatype of the inputs and outputs, but I didn't find any way to do this from the command line or directly in an embedded MATLAB function.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Comment: ok got it. Just 3 Lines of code:             mfb = find(sfroot, '-isa', 'Stateflow.EMChart', 'Name', 'test'); 
            out = get(mfb, 'Outputs');
            out.set('DataType', ['Bus: ' component_source.test]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mfb = find(sfroot, '-isa', 'Stateflow.EMChart', 'Name', 'test'); 
out = get(mfb, 'Outputs'); 
out.set('DataType', ['Bus: ' component_source.test]);
```